# Convert List<XElement> to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, xelement

I'm new to C# so this could be a simple answer. I have a List of XElements coming in from an API. I need to convert it to a datatable. How can I do that?

List of XElements:

```
<person><personid>1</personid><name>person1</name></person>
<person><personid>2</personid><name>person2</name></person>
```

I need it in the following data table format

```
    PersonID | Name
    --------------
    1         person1
    2         person2
```

Another thing is I dont know the nodes at design time. So the XElement could be of the format

```
<anyrootnode><anynumberofchildnodes/></anyrootnode>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written any code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load xelement into a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602581/load-xelement-into-a-datatable)

Comment: If you know the schema in advance, see [How to get a tablerow out of an xelement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32139449/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataTable has a function named ReadXml which is used to read Xml.

```
string xml = XElements.ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.ReadXml(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
```

Comment: This throws `DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.`